# How to access/change a variable in the initialization? JAVA

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paint

Hello fellow programmers!

So to be honest here, i'm not sure if the title question is correct, and you will see why.
Before i explain what i do, and why, here is the code snippet:

```
    JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel() {    
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            X = 1;
            Y = 1;
            g.drawImage(player.getScaledInstance(player.getHeight()/2, player.getWidth()/2, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT), X, Y, null);
        }     
};
```

So this a snippet from a custom class i made, and my question would be that, you see there is an X and Y variable, i can change their values , but that changes nothing on the impact of the actual program, my first question would be that can i change the X, and Y of this JPanel's image, and if so , how can i "refresh" the actual JPanel/Image so that it looks like it moved?

Some notes:

```
-the X, Y are global variables

-playerPanel is inside a procedure, and a global variable

-i can access X, Y since they are global variables from outside the class
```

I'm having a hard time actually writing down my problem... Hopefully you understand what i would like to accomplish.

Comment: 1. Override `paintComponent()`, not `paint()` 2. Call `super.paintComponent()` at the beginning of `paintComponent()` 3. Don't set the x/y coordinates inside the `paintComponent()` method. 4. You can force the panel to repaint by calling `panel.repaint()` 5. Variable names (that are not final) should start with a lowercase letter 6. An animation could be accomplished with a [timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for example in which you change the value for x/y every run.

Comment: Thank you! To be honest i'm messing around with rectangles, and in my project i made an image loading class, which once called, loads a chosen image into a new JPanel (as you can see from the snippet) and this JPanel is inside the class, i made the  x/y coordinates global, so i could access it from outside the class, so there is the "imageLoaded" object and i wanted to change the image's coordinate with "imageLoaded.X = insert_coordinate_here" the reason why i did this was i could move the panel around with KeyListener on the main frame, and made another "loadedImage(2)"

Comment: and i made 3 rectangles the first one was at the loadedImage's coordinates and it was the same size , the second one was the same with loadedImage2 , and the third was the intersection between the two. The loadedImage2 was not "visible" until there was an intersection , and only the intersection was visible. Now everything worked fine, but whenever i moved the loadedImage1 it was showing the intersection, but not correctly, because it was always (and only) showing the upper left corner of the image, and then i figured out , that i had to move the image on the panel itself, that is what i'm

Comment: trying to accomplish... I can edit my post, and add the whole script if needed, i would appricieate any help, i'm kinda lost. The repaint() method didn't help.  Thanks again for the comment, and advice!

Comment: OK, everything work fine now, i have no idea why .repaint() didn't work, now everything is perfect :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're main problem: Don't use an anonymous inner class if you want to give the class new mutable fields. Instead, create a separate class, it can be an inner class, but it can't be anonymous, give it fields that are needed with getters and setters. Also all that Luxx recommends is correct -- override paintCompoent, call the super method, don't declare the fields within a method...

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayerDrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    private int playerX;
    private int playerY;
    private Player player;

    public PlayerDrawingPanel(int playerX, int playerY, Player player) {
        this.playerX = playerX;
        this.playerY = playerY;
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void setPlayerX(int playerX) {
        this.playerX = playerX;
        repaint();
    }

    public void setPlayerY(int playerY) {
        this.playerY = playerY;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(player.getImage(), playerX, playerY, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed some parts of my code, and now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create global variables.
You can use `setBounds(x, y, w, h)` from Swing's JComponent to move and resize the JPanel.
Though, you have to keep in mind that a Component cannot draw outside its borders. Meaning that the `Graphics` object that is passed into `paint(Graphics g)` comes clipped and translated to fit the Component from it's parent.

So, to solve your case, you can either make your JPanel take over the whole area in which you want to draw by using `setBounds()` or you can you the LayeredLayout from your root panel to draw anywhere.

Let me exemplify the last solution. Consider `frame` to be your `JFrame` and `playerPanel` the `JPanel` that you overwrote the `paint()` method:

```
frame.setGlassPane(playerPanel);
frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

Now your playerPanel is at the topmost layer of your application, covering the whole area. This means you can draw anywhere over anything.